# UItableview scrolling problem when using tamil text

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, uifont, tamil

When I trying to display tamil characters in my `UITableview` I can't able to smoothly scroll the `tableview` but if I replace tamil characters with english characters there is no problem in scrolling.

**Any solutions ?**

Thanks in advance !!!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier         = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell                   = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) 
{
    cell                            =   [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle             =   UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;  
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor   yellowColor];

    UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [lblTitle setTag:100];
    [lblTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13]];
    [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [lblTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];
    [lblTitle release];

}

UILabel     *plblTitle      = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];

News  *pNewsObj = [appDelegate.CurrentNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

plblTitle.text = pNewsObj.pHeadLine;


return cell;
```

}

Comment: what are you using for displaying tamil characters?

Comment: i am simply parsing the text from an xml and displaying that in a UIlabel inside a UItableview

Comment: can you post code of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom table view by using scroll view, label and buttons.

And its scroll very smoothly.

For Ex.

```
In myView.h

       IBOutlet UIScrollView    *scrollView;
        UIButton                *cell[2048];
        NSInteger               cellCount;

- (void) createCell;
- (void) removeCell;


In myView.m

- (void) createCell
{
    [self removeCell];

    float x = 10.0;
    float y = 5.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [Your NSMutableArray count]; i++)
    {
        cell[cellCount] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        cell[cellCount].frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 176.0, 10.0);
        [cell[cellCount] setTitle:@"Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell[cellCount] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell[cellCount].titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
        [cell[cellCount] addTarget:self action:@selector(cellEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell[cellCount].tag = i;

        [scrollView cell[cellCount]];

        cellCount++;
        y = y + 15.0;
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, y);
}

- (void) removeCell
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cellCount; i++)
    {
        [cell[i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    cellCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chetan . I am having Three Labels one button in that cell. So i prefer to stick with UItableview.